# is regression test a white box test?

Tags: testing, regression

**Regression test vs white box test**

I used a search engine and wikipedia but I wasn't able to answer my question:

*Is* **regression test** a **white box test**?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have to be.

Black box testing has *no knowledge* of system internals: it just tests functionality.

Regression testing checks if previously working functionality is broken in a new release.

A "regression test" could use either "white box" (we "know" the internals) or "black box" (we're testing *only* the visible functionality) approaches.  Or any combination of the two approaches.